# 122233 how many permutations?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a simple question: How many six-digit numbers have the same digits as the number 122233?

I'm stuck on a such a simple problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(1,2,3)=\dfrac{6!}{2!\cdot 3!\cdot 1!}=60$

Suppose we have $6$ different elements. Hence there are $6!$ permutations. But $2$ in here $3$ times and $3$ only two times. So we divide to $2!$ and $3!$